# Knowing from which commit I have made a branch from in Subversion?

Tags: svn, subversive

I have done a branch in the past from the trunk. Is it possible to know, today, from which commit was it made from?

If yes, how? Is it possible to accomplish with Subversive's Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of version control is to preserve a detailed log of the past.

I think

`svn log --stop-on-copy`

is what you are after. I have no idea how to invoke that from Eclipse.